# Why on another machine my docker-compose app is throwing error about missing files if I included every file in my docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry, dockerhub

I wanted to ask about some errors in my docker-compose app that I cannot comprehend. I am not sure If I am making some kind of code mistake or I am misunderstanding whole concept of docker compose.

Here are things that I am doing:

1. I built docker-compose on laptop A - everything is working
2. In docker-compose.yml I changed name if my image to mynick/myimage:test
3. I pushed my "custom" image to docker hub using docker-compose push
4. I copied my docker-compose.yml file and .env file to laptop B
5. I did docker-compose --env-file env up
6. Every image was successfully downloaded from docker hub and my app started
7. After boot up of my app I am seeing errors about missing files and directories from my main app folder (which also had docker-compose and docker file inside so it should include everything already?)

And errors that I see in step 7 are for example "missing alembic.ini file". And when I manually copy it to laptop B (folder when is docker-compose.yml located) then I am seeing error "FAILED: Path doesn't exist: '/my_app/alembic"

I find it weird because my custom image had command "COPY . /my_app" so as far as I understand it should copy all the files inside the image, so it should have all the files and exactly the same folder structure?

And this folder structure looks similar to this:
My folder structure looks like that:

```
->my_app
----alembic.ini
---->alembic
-------->versions
------------.keep
--------various_stuff
----main.py
----Dockerfile
----docker-compose.yml
----various_stuff
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3-slim-buster
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /myapp
CMD 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  database:
    container_name: postgresql_db
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_EMAIL}
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    depends_on:
      - database

  myapp:
    container_name: myapp
    build: .
    image: myapp:main
    command: bash -c "alembic upgrade head && uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - database
    restart: always

  migration:
    image: myapp:main
    command: bash -c "alembic revision --autogenerate -m 'New Migration'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    depends_on:
      - myapp

  upgrade_head:
    image: myapp:main
    command: bash -c "alembic upgrade head"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    depends_on:
      - migration
```

And my docker-compose.yml after I change it to run on other computers:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  database:
    container_name: postgresql_db
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_EMAIL}
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    depends_on:
      - database

  myapp:
    container_name: myapp
    build: .
    image: dockerhubnick/myappimage:latest
    command: bash -c "alembic upgrade head && uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - database
    restart: always

  migration:
    image: dockerhubnick/myappimage:latest
    command: bash -c "alembic revision --autogenerate -m 'New Migration'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    depends_on:
      - myapp

  upgrade_head:
    image: dockerhubnick/myappimage:latest
    command: bash -c "alembic upgrade head"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    depends_on:
      - migration
```

Currently I am not sure if I am making some code related program, or I misunderstood how docker-compose works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `volume` directive in the second `docker-compose.yml` file. It is overwriting the files that you copied into the image with the contents of the local directory. You don't notice a difference on the first laptop, because the local directory contains the same files that get copied into the image. But on the second laptop you get an error, because the project files are missing.

Remove the `volume` directives in the `docker-compose.yml` file for the second laptop, and the errors should disappear. Without the `volume`, the files that you copied into the image will be used as excepted.

Comment: Thank you! That was my problem. I deleted volume part like you said and it started working like a charm, thank you! I wanted to quickly confirm one more thing, only possibility to share my app that is using docker-compose is to actually share docker-compose.yml file (and push custom image to docker hub), am I right? It is not possible to push somewhere whole "package" so others would not need any files at all?

Comment: That question is hard to answer without more context. Generally speaking, as long as you want users to execute your program on their machine, they will always have to download _something_. If you don't care if users run this on their machine, you might be able to host this as a web app so that they can access it through the browser. The best solution really depends on the app that you're building. You will probably get the best answers if you create a new question and describe what you're building and how you want users to interact with it.

Comment: Ahh, I am sorry. I was just thinking that maybe it will be possible to get everything with one simple command like `docker pull <something>`, without downloading first docker-compose file and then executing `docker-compose build`